# How to automatically align and center a string of chord diagrams with a word beneath?

Tags: center, music, justification

The following code, when compiled, produces two side-by-side chord diagrams with the word 'Major' off-center beneath. Is there an automatic way to get the word perfectly centered below the chords?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gchords}

\begin{document}

\mediumchords

\begin{center}

\chords{
\chord{}{f4p4,f3p3,f1p1,f1p1,n,n}{}
\chord{}{n,f4p4,f3p3,f1p1,f2p2,n}{}
}

Major

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the non-centered part is the chord, not the "Major". Somehow the chord includes a left margin. Maybe my "solution" works fine for you.
I tried some things to find out whether there are additional parameters which would cause the shift, but the "centering" seems to start with the lowest snare.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gchords}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}

\mediumchords

\begin{center}%
\chords{%
\hspace{-0.5cm}\chord{{2999999}}{f4p4,f3p3,f1p1,f1p1,n,n}{}}%
Major%
\end{center}%
\begin{center}%
\chords{%
\chord{t}{n,f4p4,f3p3,f1p1,f2p2,n}{}%
}%
Major%
\end{center}%

\begin{center}%
\chords{%
\hspace{-0.5cm}\chord{{2999999}}{f4p4,f3p3,f1p1,f1p1,n,n}{}%
\chord{t}{n,f4p4,f3p3,f1p1,f2p2,n}{}%
}%
Major%
\end{center}%

\begin{center}%
\chords{%
\hspace{-0.5cm}\chord{{2999999}}{f4p4,f3p3,f1p1,f1p1,n,n}{}%
\hspace{-0.5cm}\chord{t}{n,f4p4,f3p3,f1p1,f2p2,n}{}%
}%
Major%
\end{center}%


\end{document}
```

[image]